# Redirect for multiple Angular 9 apps

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2 and Angular 9.

I have 3 Angular 9 apps placed on 3 folders, Main (/), Admin (/admin) and Support (/support).

I have this code to redirect to the index page of each app:

```
@GetMapping("/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirectMain()
{
    return "forward:/index.html";
}

@GetMapping("/admin/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirectAdmin()
{
    return "forward:/admin/index.html";
}

@GetMapping("/support/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirectSupport()
{
    return "forward:/support/index.html";
}
```

But all the request are catch by the redirectMain function. What am I doing wrong? (I'm testing this functions using PostMan to make the requests to make sure this works, before trying with the Angular Router itself. Also, I'm trying with /admin and /admin/ and /support and /support/).

Comment: Looks like `@GetMapping("/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")` is too broad and catches everything.

Comment: What change do I need to make to get this working?

Comment: I would put Main in `/main`. Then you don't need to worry about the wildcard.

Comment: Sure, I thought about that before, but my client doesn't like it, and they want the root URL.

Comment: I'm not sure how spring finds the correct handler. Try moving the one that is broad to the bottom. So maybe then it will evaluate the specifics ones first before evaluating the root.

Comment: I tryed that also, changing the order of the functions declarations, but with the same result. My last resource is adding the HttpServletRequest injection and check manually for the specifyc URLs and then fallback to the broader URL.

Comment: Try to supply a specific regex for your main one that does **NOT** start with either /admin or /support. something like this: `^(?!(\/admin|\/suppport)$).*/path:...`. I haven't checked it of course and you'll probably need to go back and forth a bit to get it to work but it's a start.